# git config - double diff and merge tool

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I checked my git settings today and I found that I have 2 different diff and mergetools there.  Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not *normal*, but it is not anything to worry about. With your config, you could for example run the following commands

```
git difftool -t sourcetree HEAD~ HEAD
git difftool -t p4mergetool HEAD~ HEAD
```

which would open the diff between the last two commits in the corresponding diff-tool. And you have set `p4mergetool` as default, so if you don't specify the tool, that one will be picked.